# Google Analytics - one UA for multiple domains

Tags: google-analytics

We produce a white label site and our managers want to track usage accross all users of our product. Each user is on a different domain. Management do not want to create a new UA code for each customer. They want one UA code, and for that to be the repository for all data collected across all domains.

It's the exact same product on all domains, but skinned differently.

Google Analytics only allows you to specify **one default domain** when you set up a UA code. Requests from other domains do not have their visits registered against that UA code. It is looking very much like you are required to specify one UA code per domain.

1. Is this true or is there a way of specifying multiple domains in google analyics? (if so, how?)
2. If there isn't, does anyone know of any alternative analytics
   programs that allow you to collect data from multiple domains into
   the same bucket?

Comment: I thought you should know I reached this page by typing into Google: "2 ua codes one website"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain in the settings has mainly cosmetical value ([1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain)).  The Google Analytics Code will work on all domains, unless you set the cookie domain to a specific domain name (in which case the code cannot set cookies on other domain names and will fail to work).

In Universal Analytics a tracker that works on all domains would be created with

```
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
```

"Auto" meaning that the cookie domain is set to window.location.hostname.

In classic Analytics you'd simply remove any setDomainName-Calls from the tracking code (if any).

If you want to track multiple domains as one you'd need [cross domain tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain), but that does not seem to be your usecase.

---

[1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain) Google Analytics reports display only url paths by default. If you hit the "view page" icon (a small square after the url path in some reports) Google Analytics will try to open the url in a new browser windows and will preprend the domain name from the settings. As far as I can tell this is the only use for that setting

Comment: So what's to stop someone grabbing a competitors UA code and inserting it into a bogus site? There'd be massive cross-pollution of data unless there were checks surely?

Comment: Nothing, really, afaik there are no checks implemented by Google. If you notice something like that you'd filter by hostname and accept only traffic that originates from your own domain. Even that would probably not protect against an attack via the measurement protocol.

Comment: Can confirm - it does not matter which domain the tracking code is on.

Comment: I am attempting to set up this exact scenario (I think) and it's not working.  We have a single site that has multiple domain aliases that are unrelated to each other (domain1.com, sub1.domain2.com, sub2.domain3.com, etc.).  The only domain that gets tracked is the one the ID was created for, sub1.domain2.com.  My tracking code is this:

Comment: (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
     (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
     m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-2', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');